# How to use InteractionRequestTrigger in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, prism-4

How to use **InteractionRequestTrigger** in windows phone?

I can't find this class in assembly **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity** or assembly **Microsoft.Practices.Prism**. Please, help me to find example code.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [`Tailspin.Phoneclient`](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) project. I think you'll find the dlls in the project. Add references to your project. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490766.aspx)

Comment: The Tailspin.Phoneclient was made on Windows Phone 7.0 version. If I take thr assemblies **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity** and **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.** from this sample - all worked, but the new build [prism for mango](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/75760) not worked. I can't get access from XAML to **InteractionResultTRrigger**.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at the [codeplex](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com):

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SubmitErrorInteractionRequest}" EventName="Raised">
        <prismInteractionRequest:MessageBoxAction />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```